# How to force !important from a parent element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to force a specific attribute on children elements, from the level of the parent. I thought that using `!important` would be enough, but it is not taken into account on children elements:

```css
.up {
  color: red !important;
}

.down {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="up">
  <div class="down">
    this text should be red
  </div>
</div>
```

**Is it possible to cascade `!important` down to the children elements?**

Comment: I don't see a scenario where you would want this? Why not give the child `color: inherit`?

Comment: !important will work.. but, i have a doubt.. Do u want the "this text should be red" text is blue color and rest of them into red color?

Comment: @MarcHjorth: there may be better solutions to my problem: I have a several `div` under a parent one (the one with the class `up` in my example). They are all styled in specific ways but I have a case where the class `up` will be dynamically applied (via vue.js) and will grey-out everything. Instead of having the condition on each `div` I wanted to have that exceptional case set up on the parent and force it (via `!important`) on the  children. I am far from being fluent with CSS so, again, there may be better solutions.

Comment: @Manikandan2811: sorry, I do not understand your question. I want the color set up to `blue` by the class `down` to be overridden by `red`, from the class above.

Comment: You should target the child elements then. This way you can write a selector like this `."parent name" ."toggle vue class"  ".class" child element { color: grey; }`. And the child elements will change styles if their parent has the "toggle vue class". Hope you understand :)

Comment: Of course it doesn’t work this way. The parent can have gotten its color any way you want, `!important` or not - that does not change the fact that your `.down` children have their own color specified, they are not inheriting it from their parent to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
.up > * {
  color: red !important;
}
```

This will affect all direct child elements. (You could probably erase the `!important` in this case, but that depends on the order of the rules and on theselector specifity of the rules for the child elements)

If you want to apply it to ALL children (not just the direct ones), use it without the `>`, like

```
.up * {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```css
.down {
  color: blue;
}
.up > * {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="up">
  <div class="down">
    this text should be red
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
.up>.down {
    color: red;
 }
```

I hope this is the solution that what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
.up > .down {
  color: red;
}

.down {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u add the html like below the code and ur css will be correct..

**HTML:**

```
<div class="up">
  this text should be blue
  <div class="down">
    this text should be red
  </div>
</div>
```

Or Do u want the reverse color then, change the css code

**css**

```
.up {
  color: blue !important;
}
.down {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="up myclass">
  <div class="down">
    this text should be red
  </div>
</div>

.up {
  color: red !important;
}
.down {
  color: blue;
}
.myclass .down {color:initial; color:inherit;}
```

Whenever you have this kind of situation if you are working other person's code then never edit the initial code because you never know what that code is working for. In this situation you need to do is create your own class and edit the children with your own class.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the CSS anyway, you can do this without needing `!important`.

```css
.up {
  color: red;
}

:not(.up) > .down {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="up">
  <div class="down">
    this text should be red
  </div>
</div>
<div class="down">
  this text should be blue
</div>
```